# Hide FTP login details from the running config

Tags: cisco

We are using the below commands to save configs onto an FTP server, I am wondering if we can hide the login details as they show in clear text in the running config.

```
#show run | b archive
    archive
     log config
      logging enable
      logging size 200
      notify syslog contenttype plaintext
      hidekeys
     path ftp://myusername:mypassword@10.10.10.10/$h-$t
     write-memory
     time-period 40320
```

Comment: if you truly car about protecting the password then don't use ftp. With this protocol the  password is sent in clear text over the network. use SCP instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations, applications, and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: @RonMaupin Its about hiding the password when you do a show run on a Cisco device.

Comment: OK. Using FTP, it will all be plaintext. JFL told you to use SCP.

Comment: As JFL has pointed out, you should be more concerned about transmitting your credentials in plaintext over the network than anything else.

Comment: Thanks for reopening it. If using SCP means that the login credentials are hidden in the config as well as in transmission then I am happy to accept that and I will look into it. But if the config still shows "path scp://myusername:mypassword@10.10.10.10/$h-$t" then that doesnt actually answer my question.